# Print three columns with awk, then sets of three columns

Tags: awk

I want to create a number of files from a much larger file, dividing by columns. For example, the header of my larger file looks like this:

`Name Chr Position SNP1A SNP1B SNP1C SNP2A SNP2B SNP2C SNP3A SNP3B SNP3C`

and I want to create these files:

`Name Chr Position SNP1A SNP1B SNP1C`

`Name Chr Position SNP2A SNP2B SNP2C`

`Name Chr Position SNP3A SNP3B SNP3C`

I've been trying to use awk, but I'm a bit of a novice with it, so my command currently reads:

```
for ((i=1; i<=440;i++)); do awk -f printindivs.awk inputfile done
```

Where printindivs.awk is:
`{print $1 $2 $3 $((3*$i)+1) $((3*$i)+2) $((3*$i)+3))}`

The output I'm getting suggests that my way of trying to get the sets of three is wrong: how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Move the `for` loop into the `awk` code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily will just a simple `awk` script:

```
$ awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i+=3)print $1,$2,$3,$i,$(i+1),$(i+2) > ("out"++j)}' file
```

The output files will be in `out[1..n]`:

```
$ cat out1
Name Chr Position SNP1A SNP1B SNP1C

$ cat out2
Name Chr Position SNP2A SNP2B SNP2C

$ cat out3
Name Chr Position SNP3A SNP3B SNP3C
```

Comment: This prints individual files for each row of the file. I want to print the columns

Comment: Look at the question you asked, you don't mention columns once! You show the expected output and that is what my solution does. You `want to print the columns` what do you even mean by that!

Comment: The title is "Print three columns with awk, then sets of three columns", I use the word columns explicitly in the text, and I refer to a header. As it happens, I was being stoopid and just need to use cut.